# How to safely provide free query access on an open database

Tags: web-services, relational-database, denial-of-service

**Background:** My state government has a website that provides financial data in the name of "government transparency", but I'm quite unhappy with the way it is presented. It's an awkward old-fashioned website with no API, no way to download the data, and the website itself provides no aggregate analysis. You can find the salary and travel reimbursement records of any state employee by name, but it takes some concerted effort. And there is certainly no easy way of getting answers to useful questions like "what is the average high school teacher's salary?" So, as a first step, I just screen-scraped a big chunk of this information, which is now sitting in json format on a GitHub repo.

So my next step is present this data in useful ways. Certainly I will try to do some analysis and graphics myself, provide a RESTful API, and provide a tarball containing the entire data set. But there's another thing I want but am not sure about...

**The question:** If I put this data into a relational database, how can I "safely" expose that database system for general-purpose public queries? I can't imagine it's a good idea to simply write a web service that executes arbitrary SQL selects, since that's an open invitation for anyone to tie up my processor with long-running queries (malicious or not).

Is there such a thing as a SQL subset, or different query language altogether, that can guarantee upper bounds of the complexity of query evaluation? Or am I overthinking this - maybe the right answer is as trivial as setting a low maximum query time on the DBMS?

Comment: One person suggested: "Use EXPLAIN plan costing to bound it?" - Interesting idea, although I'm not sure whether it's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply make a database server available on the open internet, depending on your risk-tolerance.

Which databases are available to you?

What are the requirements in terms of segregating data by user roles? Can anyone access it? Only those with login roles? Different data for different login roles?

You would want a db that supports role-based security, and give `SELECT` only permissions to the proper tables.

Make sure your root user can only connect from a specific network and that the password is incredibly complex, and login occurs over TLS. Consider fail2ban as well.

You can use the `workmem` parameter in PostgreSQL to limit query memory usage. MySQL supports user query throttling. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-resources.html